# The flaws of the Darboux formulation

Tags: calculus, integration

I have just started studying the Darboux formulation for integration, and I assume that for anyone who studies basic integration, the first example of a non-integrable function is the Dirichlet function. This function's upper sums are all equal to $1$ and all the lower sums are equal to $0$, and hence not integrable.

Intuitively, I would think that the integral should be zero, since there are only countably many rationals in $[0,1]$ and uncountably many irrationals in $[0,1]$. In other words, there are some points where the function gets the value of $1$, but there are many (many) other points, more precisely - most of the points (informally speaking) that take the value of $0$. This leads to the suggestions (that seems reasonable to me) that the integral should be zero.

After some research, I have found that there is the Lebesgue integration formulation that does respond well to this kind of behaviors.

Since I have yet to acquire the tools of measure theory, my question is this: Why does the Darboux formalism fail to "capture" this kind of behavior? What is the conceptual failure of Darboux's idea, which seems very natural and correct?

Comment: +1 for a nice question! I don't have time now to try to come up with an intuitive way of seeing what the Darboux (equivalently, the Riemann) integral distinguishes that the Lebesgue integral doesn't, but I would expect this question to generate some good discussions.

Comment: The Darboux integral, defined in terms of upper and lower sums, is equivalent to the Riemann integral, defined in terms of [tagged partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Partitions_of_an_interval). These tagged partitions are a special case of a more general notion used in the very similar definition of the [gauge (or Henstock-Kurzweil) integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral). [This PDF](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2006/PAPERS/Herschlag.pdf) gives a nice little introduction to the gauge integral and in Section $3$ shows ...

Comment: ... that it gives the value $0$ for the integral of Dirichlet’s function over $[0,1]$. An examination of the mechanics of this calculation should give you a clearer picture of why the Darboux/Riemann integral can’t handle this function.

Answer (score 4):

The Darboux integral is essentially the same as the Riemann integral.
It is incapable of distinguishing between two functions $f$ and $g$ if $f$ and $g$ have the same sup and inf on every interval of positive length.  You might say, Darboux is  not interested in the cardinality of sets of the form $\{x \in I: f(x) \in [t,\infty)\}$ or $\{x \in I: f(x) \in (-\infty,s]\}$ (where $I$ is an interval), just in whether or not those sets are empty.